# Why is my NHibernate query failing with an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using Fluent NHibernate and in certain cases my query is failing with a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

It seems that the issue has to do with the combination of using *escaped column name(s)* in the mapping and calling *`CreateSQLQuery().AddEntity()`*. It works fine if none of the columns need escaping or if I instead use `CreateCriteria<Employee>()`.

```
public class Employee {
    public virtual string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeMapping : ClassMap<Employee> {
    public EmployeeMapping() {
        Table("Employees");
        Id(e => e.EmployeeNumber)
            .Column("No_");
        Map(e => e.Username)
            .Column("`E-mail Login`"); // Note the escaped column name
    }
}

public class SqlRepository {
    ...
    public IList<Employee> ListEmployees() {
        using (ISession session = _sessionBuilder.GetSession()) {
            return session
                .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT No_, [E-mail Login] FROM Employees")
                .AddEntity(typeof(Employee))
                .List<Employee>();
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `ListEmployees()` results in a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

However, if I change the `CreateSQLQuery().AddEntity()` call to `CreateCriteria<Employee>()`, it works fine. But my actual SQL is more complex so I don't think that will work for me.

Or, if I change the Username mapping to `Map(e => e.Username).Column("Username");` and change the SQL query to `SELECT No_, [E-mail Login] AS Username FROM Employees`, it works fine. But this would break the mapping for other places in my code that do use `CreateCriteria<Employee>()`. And I can't change the table schema at the moment.

Why is this failing? Do you have any other suggestions besides what I mentioned? Thanks.

I am using Fluent NHibernate 1.0, NHibernate 2.1.0.4000 and SQL Server 2005.

Here is the stack trace:

```
 NHibernate.ADOException was unhandled
   Message="could not execute query\r\n[ SELECT No_, [E-mail Login] FROM Employees ]\r\n[SQL: SELECT No_, [E-mail Login] FROM Employees]"
   Source="NHibernate"
   SqlString="SELECT No_, [E-mail Login] FROM Employees"
   StackTrace:
     at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
     at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
     at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
     at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
     at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
     at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
     at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List[T](NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)
     at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List[T]()
     at NHibernateTest.Core.SqlRepository.ListEmployees() in C:\dev\NHibernateTest\NHibernateTest\SqlRepository.cs:line 14
     at NHibernateTest.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\NHibernateTest\NHibernateTest.Console\Program.cs:line 8
     at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
     at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
     Message="[E-mail Login]"
     Source="System.Data"
     StackTrace:
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
    at NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
    at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
    at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String[] names, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
    at NHibernate.Type.AbstractType.Hydrate(IDataReader rs, String[] names, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
    at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Hydrate(IDataReader rs, Object id, Object obj, ILoadable rootLoadable, String[][] suffixedPropertyColumns, Boolean allProperties, ISessionImplementor session)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadFromResultSet(IDataReader rs, Int32 i, Object obj, String instanceClass, EntityKey key, String rowIdAlias, LockMode lockMode, ILoadable rootPersister, ISessionImplementor session)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceNotYetLoaded(IDataReader dr, Int32 i, ILoadable persister, EntityKey key, LockMode lockMode, String rowIdAlias, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, Object optionalObject, IList hydratedObjects, ISessionImplementor session)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRow(IDataReader rs, ILoadable[] persisters, EntityKey[] keys, Object optionalObject, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, LockMode[] lockModes, IList hydratedObjects, ISessionImplementor session)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
     InnerException:
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by using aliases for the column names and using a result transformer. It's not ideal since it ignores my mapping and requires setting an alias for each column. But it works for now.

```
public class SqlRepository {
    ...
    public IList<Employee> ListEmployees() {
        using (ISession session = _sessionBuilder.GetSession()) {
            return session
                .CreateSQLQuery(@"
                    SELECT No_ AS EmployeeNumber, [E-mail Login] AS Username 
                    FROM Employees")
                .AddScalar("EmployeeNumber", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .AddScalar("Username", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Employee>())
                .List<Employee>();
        }
    }
}
```

Any better solutions? Could there be a bug in (Fluent) NHibernate causing the original issue?

Comment: Thanks, it helped!